# Item with margin-top has margin outside of containing box

Tags: html, css, margins

I have something to this effect:

```
#div {
   background: green; 
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
}

h1 {
   margin-top: 100px;
}
```

(And obviously there is some HTML to go with it.)

Now when viewed in the browser the `h1` shows at the very top of the `#div` and the `100px` margin goes on top of the `#div`.

Can anyone suggest a reason?

(The code is a little too complicated to insert the relevant parts so if no-one can give me an answer then I will post it and maybe someone will spot an error or something.)

Comment: could you please submit your html code ?

Comment: We need to see more code than this. The code you've given should work fine.

Comment: Okay, was about to add code, but it seems that using padding works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add padding instead. I've seen this kind of problem before. If the padding does the the same thing then try putting a container div around but #div and the h1 then add the margin. If you are just wanting to move the h1 down from the #div then padding is your best bet since it will "Push the h1 further into the #div 'box'".

Comment: Padding will make it work. For some reason margins don't play well with headings.

Comment: Okay, it does work. Not sure if its only the heading though because I tried changing it to a div and it still did the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to happen a lot when 2 element are at the very top of the page with no in between elements. Still haven't quite figured out why. Glad to know padding does the trick though.

Comment: I posted an answer which explains the problem (applying hack without knowing why is a bad thing !)

Comment: I must admit I didn't know why (thanks for that, very informative), but using padding instead of margin is hardly a hack!

Answer (score 17):

This is not related to the H1 tag. This is what we call margin collapse.

You can find a post about this subject here : 
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

you have several solutions :

- use padding instead
- add overflow: auto on your parent div
- add transparent top border to the parent div

Comment: I personally would go against using the overflow:auto styling because of the problems that could arise in other browsers. This is just a personal preference though.

Comment: I agree, this is what I call a hack solution. The best is to read the post on the margin collapse to understand the problem and after that found the better solution for a specific case

Comment: Okay I fully understand now, when I wrote the code originally the `#div` had overflow: hidden (and there were no problems) and then when I changed that then 'margin-collapse' happened. I just wasn't exactly sure what I had changed to have that affect.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem by making all of my header tags (h1-h6) `display: inline-block;`. As inline elements with margins, they can overflow like that, but as inline blocks they behave a little more nicely with others.

Comment: inline-block worked for me, but h1-h6 are block-level elements